# Parsing a Twitter date with Joda Time

Tags: java, twitter, jodatime, date-parsing

Twitter gives me a date such as "Wed, 27 Mar 2013 15:12:14 +0000".
I'm trying to parse it with:

```
DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

But it fails:

```
Invalid format: "Wed, 03 Apr 2013 10:35:35 +0000" is malformed at "+0000"
```

I've tried replacing `ZZZZZ` with `z`, `Z`, and `ZZZ`, but no change. Can these dates be parsed this way?

Comment: Note: Other questions that appear to be asking the same thing are in fact using a different format.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although you've said you've used a single `Z` in the format pattern, this works:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = 
    DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTime dateTime = format.parseDateTime("Wed, 27 Mar 2013 15:12:14 +0000");
```

When parsing this format a single `Z` timezone character will suffice, 4 is invalid:

> Z       time zone offset/id          zone          -0800; -08:00; America/Los_Angeles

For more see [the javadoc](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

While the accepted answer is correct, The twitter dates that I'm getting from the API are in a different. This alternate parser works for that format:

```
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy").withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH)
String input = "Sat Jan 14 01:50:54 +0000 2017"
DateTime dateTime = format.parseDateTime(input)
```